Why is not rendermode changes back to SSR in .NET8 Blazor?
I am using the following code to change the rendermodes programatically:
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/login") ? null : InteractiveServer;
}

I have an SSR /login page where I am using cookie authentication. If I open /forgot-password page without logging in, the rendermode changes to InteractiveServer, but after that if I go back in the browser to the /login page and finally try to log in, It throws me an System.InvalidOperationException: 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.' exception because rendermode remains InteractiveServer.
I tried to solve this issue with the NavigationManager LocationChanged Event but it does not worked great, beacuse the event not triggered when the application started. Which is the best way to change the rendermode based on the current URL of my application?

From my comprehension it is not the blazor issue, as your project should work as expected if not go back in the browser based on your description. You need to confirm if the blazor component refreshed when going back as we cannot set the headers once data is written to the response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085572/headers-are-read-only-exception-when-writing-to-httpresponse  this question provides a thought which is to pre-writing the response. I tested with custom middleware to dynamically switch the rendermode but didn't got it work. Please verify.
